# Listing todays appointment mysql query

Tags: mysql, date

Hi Guys can someone help me please , i am trying to list todays appointment instead of showing all datas from database.

here is my code which display all data, i want to print out only the appointments which are booked for today

```
public function getComing(){
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');

    $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where";
    $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id  date = currAND status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'"ORDER BY date';
    $sql.=$qualifier;


    return  $valuearray = $connection->getArray($sql);

}
```

i tried may best but i can not do it this what i have done to print out todays appointment but it doesnt working.

```
  //here is the change 
    $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where date = CURDATE()";
    $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id  date = currAND status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'"ORDER BY date';
    $sql.=$qualifier;
```

i appreciate if someone can help me with this

Many thanks

Comment: given you've got MULTIPLE sql syntax errors (`currAND`?), perhaps you should be checking your `query()` calls for errors... since you don't mention any error messages, your code probably is simply assuming nothing could ever fail. BAD assumption. **ALWAYS** assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Additionally to what MarcB correctly points out, you're missing an "AND" between the "date=CURDATE()" AND "bookings...", then you should remove the "date=curr" (as it seems you removed HALF the query), and you're also missing an "space" before the ORDER BY

Comment: Marc Thanks for replying my post, i only have a problem with query the code is running no syntax error and no error messages but the result is not coming up as i was expecting,

Comment: //here is the change 
  $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where date = CURDATE()";
  $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id AND status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'"ORDER BY date';
  $sql.=$qualifier;

Comment: @user3802124 - Look at DMorillo's comment; your query right now is invalid MySQL. Do you have access to either phpMyAdmin or a command-line prompt? If you try to run your query (which boils down to `select * from bookings,bookers where date = CURDATE() bookings.booker_id = bookers.id AND status="approve"ORDER BY date`), you'll see a few errors.

Comment: i use php my admin and no errors at all , nothing returned as well

Answer (score 0):

Two things to verify:

1. Does the `date` field stores only the date, or is it a `DATETIME` field? If it is `DATETIME`, I recommend you replace your `where` condition with `date(`date`) = curdate()`. In either case, you may need to enclose the `date` field in backticks.
2. Check the spaces! For example, you are missing a space before `order by`

One more thing:

I see you are building your query string concatenating values from a variable. That can open the door to [SQL injection attacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I recommend you to use [prepared statements](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?198447-How-can-you-update-a-record-with-a-prepared-statement).

Comment: it only store date no time,  dont worry this not the code i am releasing thanks for that caution

Comment: i even change it as you can see the code but it doesnt work //here is the change 
  $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where date(date)=curdate()";
  $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id AND status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'"ORDER BY date';
  $sql.=$qualifier;

Comment: Two things: 1. Try to check any error messages (I am not quite familiar with PHP, but there must be a way to check the error messages); 2. Try to print the query and execute directly in your server (on the CLI if possible, or anotehr tool like Workbench or phpAdmin) and check any syntax errors (I insist: add a space before `order by`)